# iOS Simulator: No file exists at the address "(null)"

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

I am trying to drag images into the iOS simulator and I'm getting the response `No file exists at the address "(null)".` in safari.  Also, if I search on google for an image and try to save it to the photo library on the simulator they do not get added.  I have successfully added photos to the simulator the following ways in the past.  I need to get this working for an image editing app I am working on.

I have tried updating the simulator, using the Reset Content and Settings, restarting Xcode and the simulator but nothing seems to work.

Comment: try also deleting the derived data in /Users/[username]/Library/Developer/Xcode

Comment: if it doesn't work and you have performed the same steps in the past and it worked, it either was wrong in the first place, or maybe now you are using another iOS/Xcode version. Either way, there's not much for us to figure out without at least a bit of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem.  If you run into this issue you are going to want to delete Xcode and all of its components (iOS simulator, instrument, etc).  Reinstall Xcode and the iOS Simulator will allow you to save images from google again as well as drag and drop your images into the simulator.

If you are running on Yosemite and want to run Xcode 5.1.1 you will need to go to Developer Downloads located here: https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action in order to install it.  If you don't it will open in the Mac App store and tell you there is a compatibility issue.

Answer (score 0):

On the simulator, search in safari the image you want. Then double tap on the image really fast. It will ask you if you want to save the image. Click it and it will save the image in photos in the simulator.     This worked for me. It is better than deleting Xcode and then reinstalling it:)

Comment: This method stopped working for because of some internal error.  When I would save from google the images would not appear and the photos app would crash.  I can now successfully dave from google again after reinstalling Xcode.  It was a funky error not many people seem to have so in the rare case the reinstall seems to be the only way